# Send email from telerik report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, email-attachments, telerik-reporting

I want to send an email as pdf attachment without save/export it somewhere from the telerik report viewer but I cant find a way.

Also when I am on debug mode and view the designer I see this button and on the properties doesn't have anything for emails.

[image]

When I run the project on the browser this button doesn't show.
Anyone knows why?

I tried to make a button with this code but I couldn't convert the report to pdf from my code .

```
 protected void RadButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string type = Request.Params["type"];
            string no = Request.Params["no"];
            string stat = Request.Params["stat"];

            //Session["compcode"] = Request.Params["compcode"];

            var instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
            instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = new Reports.Report1();
            instanceReportSource.Parameters.Add("docno", no);
            instanceReportSource.Parameters.Add("doctype", type);
            instanceReportSource.Parameters.Add("docstat", stat);

            try
            {
                // Create the Outlook application.
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                // Create a new mail item.
                Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                // Set HTMLBody. 
                //add the body of the email
                oMsg.HTMLBody = "Hello, Jawed your message body will go here!!";
                //Add an attachment.
                String sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
                int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
                int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
                //now attached the file
                Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add("here must be the report as pdf", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
                //Subject line
                oMsg.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
                // Add a recipient.
                Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
                // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
                Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("xxxxx@gmail.com");
                oRecip.Resolve();
                // Send.
                oMsg.Send();
                // Clean up.
                oRecip = null;
                oRecips = null;
                oMsg = null;
                oApp = null;
            }//end of try block
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string ep = ex.ToString();
            }//end of catch


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The button you have circled above is to show/hide the parameter area of the report viewer.  If you look at there documentation for the Report Viewer it will explain how to customize the tool bar, which would allow you to add an email button onto the toolbar. Then in your code behind you will have to render the report in some format, probably pdf, into a memory stream and then attach that to your email engine. They have an old example of how to email a report here: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/send-telerik-report-as-email-attachment.

Comment: This doesn't help me, is not clear how to create custom tool bar.

Comment: You can create a custom tool bar by overriding the style for the ReportViewer TargetType. I would recommend searching Telerik blogs for an example on the version of the ReportViewer you are using.